# python: Selenium webdriver and hanging proxy issue

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am trying to understand how to handle cases when calls which are perfomed through proxies are hanging. For example I have this code:

```
def call_with_proxy(ip, port):
    profile = FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', ip)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', port)
    profile.update_preferences()
    driver= webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    driver.get("http://somewebsite.com")
```

The proxy is taken from free proxies list here https://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/

Some times everythig works and I am getting the page I am requesting. But sometimes I am getting a blank firefox page (where I can see some elements of the website is being loaded, e.g. css), and this process lasts for a very long time. E.g. session is not being closed even after 10 minutes of such waiting time. I want to ask if there is a way, to automatically close browser if for example page is not loading for some time, or for example the test I am performing stopped execution (due to some reason related to proxies)

Comment: perhaps some of the proxy servers are just very slow?

Comment: Well it is very slow, and some point. But the idea is that Selenium needs to drop connection (I mean to close session) inthe case

Answer (score 1):

In java we have:

```
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

From the doc:

> pageLoadTimeout
>
> WebDriver.Timeouts pageLoadTimeout(long time,
>                                    java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit)
>
> Sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before
>   throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, page loads can be
>   indefinite.
>
> Parameters:
>       time - The timeout value.
>       unit - The unit of time. Returns:
>       A Timeouts interface.

Quick Googling shows:

```
webDriver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
```

for Python. Try this in `try-catch` (or `try-except` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Implement a heartbeat system using queues or other active runtime objects (ie/ weblistener). If you know the maximum runtime for the site script as a whole, you can use SE-Grid like functionality.

If you have variable times on the site, and are only worried about the initial load time, a heartbeat system is the only way I can think of.

Comment: Try to provide a detailed and documented answer. This kind of suggestion are considered to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I would recommend to use it instead of keeping it. Hope you can get help and help from/to SO community.